# Elasticsearch: span_near with a large slop within a span_near with a small slop

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

How would you build a json Elasticsearch query that looks like this (in english):

```
foo WITHIN 1 (biz AND buz)
```

I expect the query to return documents where both `biz` and `buz` exist, and also, where the word `foo` is adjacent to one of those words.

For example, the following documents should match:

- foo biz bar bar bar buz
- bar bar foo biz bar buz

The following documents should **not** match:

- foo biz
- foo bar biz buz
- biz bar foo bar buz

---

**My Original Solution**

My first idea was to use `span_near`, and for its first clause, use the `foo` term, and for its second clause, use a boolean `AND` operating on `biz` and `buz`. However, in Elasticsearch, you cannot use booleans within spans, you can only put other spans within spans. Further, there is no `span_and` command.  Accordingly, you must simulate the boolean `AND` with another `span_near` with a large slop.

The solution I tried is:

```
{'span_near': {'clauses': [{'span_term': {'text': 'foo'}},
                           {'span_near': {'clauses': [{'span_term': {'text': 'biz'}},
                                                      {'span_term': {'text': 'buz'}}],
                                          'in_order': False,
                                          'slop': 1000000}}],
               'in_order': False,
               'slop': 0}}
```

Notice that we simulate `AND` with a slop of `1000000` (effectively infinite for my domain). Unfortunately, the above query **does not work**. Instead, the above query returns all documents with the words `foo`, `biz`, and `buz`, and where the word `foo` occurs between the occurrences of `biz` and `buz`.

---

**Another Solution, But Onerous**

Another solution is to convert the original query into:

```
(biz AND buz) AND ((foo WITHIN 1 biz) OR (foo WITHIN 1 buz))
```

This seems very difficult to implement as one would need to parse for `AND` keywords within a `span_near` operation and do the necessary conversions.

---

**Another Solution, Less Onerous, But Very Ugly**

Another solution would be to go back to CS 101 and take advantage of [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) and use the `span_not` query to effectively make the following:

```
foo WITHIN 1 NOT (NOT biz OR NOT buz)
```

**Update**: This second solution does not work either. The `span_not` query is not a true `NOT`. It takes two operators an `include` and an `exclude` and effectively works like `a AND NOT b`. There is no `match_all` for spans, so you cannot simply set `a` to everything.

*Note*: I am using Elasticsearch, but this question would apply equally to Lucene using their Java primitives.

Comment: Can you provide an example of data that should match and data that shouldn't match? (meaning actual documents and a sample query)

Comment: Oh, so you want to translate a pseudo-language query into ES queries :-). Well, then your request is much more complicated and an SO post I don't think will help you. This is a serious planning and serious design task.

Comment: I am designing as we speak. Note that this simple query: `(a AND b) w/3 (c AND d)` will eventually convert into this monster: `a AND b AND c AND d AND (a w/3 c OR a w/3 d OR b w/3 c OR b w/3 d)`

Comment: What I meant by design is a list of rules/restrictions when you think about what you can offer through this pseudo-language. What is allowed and what not, how many "deep" levels of inner queries allowed etc. I see you have brackets, ANDs, ORs, "w/3" (whatever that is), WITHINs.  I offered you a solution based on what you described initially, but what I mentioned above is important. These being said, your requirement is not easy and you might not get the desired output from SO users.